# How to use length and rlike using logical operator inside when clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Want to check if the column has values that have certain length and contains only digits.
The problem is that the `.rlike` or `.contains` returns a `Column` type. Something like

```
.when(length(col("abc")) == 20 & col("abc").rlike(...), myValue)
```

won't work as `col("abc").rlike(...)` will return `Column` and unlike `length(col("abc")) == 20` which returns `Boolean` (*length() however also returns Column*). How do I combine the two?

Comment: You are looking for the `===` operator that creates a boolean column. Your expression should be: `(length(col("abc")) === 20) && col("abc").rlike(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a bit of searching in compiled code, found this

```
def when(condition : org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value : scala.Any) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

Therefore the conditions in `when` must return `Column` type. `length(col("abc")) == 20` was evaluating to `Boolean`.

Also, found this function with the following signature

```
def equalTo(other : scala.Any) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

So, converted the whole expression to this

```
.when(length(col("abc")).equalTo(20) && col("abc").rlike(...), myValue)
```

Note that the logical operator is `&&` and not `&`.

Edit/Update : @Histro's comment is correct.

Comment: `Column::equalTo()` is really meant to be used in Java code. In Scala, the same functionality comes as the `===` operator.